# When i run this code snippet several times which generates a random even number in python it prints "None" for some times. Why is this happening?

Tags: python-3.x, random

When i run this code several times it prints "None" for some times. Why is this happening

```
import random
def randomeven():
    n=int(r.random()*100)
    if n%2==0:
       return n
    else:
       randomeven()

print(randomeven())
```

Comment: In the `else` case, what is returned then?

Comment: return randomeven()

Without that, the method returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return randomeven()`

Otherwise you are returning void/None from the function.

So, you will get `None` back, when the first random number is not even.

```
randomeven()
 |
 ---> (generates 15) calls itself, returns None
       |
       ---> (generates 2) returns 2
             |
         <---- (2 is returned)
       |
 <------ (returns None)
```

I recommend using a debugger to figure this sort of thing out.